# Is Stack Overflow the right place to share an open-source project and ask for peer review?

Tags: discussion

Is it a bad idea to ask a question like *"what do you think about this tool?"* on Stack Overflow, so if you don't have a blog or want to reach a broader audience you can have more reviews and feedback on it?

Where to advertise a github project ?

Comment: It's definitely not the right place for this! Github is a good place to start I think

Comment: But how to advertise your github then ?

Comment: There's SE CodeReview site. May be it's better to ask there.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what's the point of downvoting when one told me it's the right place ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222227/is-stackoverflow-the-right-place-to-share-an-open-source-project-and-ask-for-pee?noredirect=1#comment52327384_32222227

Comment: @FrançoisRichard Delete that post since it is in the wrong place.

Comment: AFAIK, code Review is good for pieces of code, but not for giving feedback on tools and applications, @πάνταῥεῖ . Re the downvotes, they tend to be different on Meta and can mean "no" or "I disagree", or "you should have read the FAQ that make it clear that promotion of products is not allowed". You won't lose any reputation points because of them. This question is in the right place now

Comment: I'm looking for a place to have peer reviews not on big complete applications or tool but for example a specific implementation on some front-end framework like backbone or react. Once it's on my github where to advertise it so I can have feedbacks ?

Comment: @FrançoisRichard you can put a link to your GitHub account in your profile

Comment: @jonsharpe I understand but once I did that how to advertise the github so people are just aware of the existence of the github and could potentially try and give feedbacks ?

Comment: Social media? SO is definitely not the correct place for this.

Comment: @FRancoisRichard while definitely a good practice to have, why does it HAVE to be on Stack Overflow? This is not the be all end all of all things programming. If it doesn't fit here, it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You basically can't. The current rules laid out in the in help center explicitly forbid this, as explained in the topic [promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

> If the only reason you're here is to sell something or drive traffic to your site, then please avoid posting answers. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; [contact our ad sales team](https://stackexchange.com/about/contact) for details. We also offer [free community promotion ads](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

Stack Overflow is not known for being a great social network. Attracting the attention of users for your personal benefit is not in the core values of this community. It is even frowned upon, disliked and greeted with down votes once noticed.

The only place within the SE network to promote/present your self is your user profile.

You could off-course mention occasionally, and only when relevant, your open source project. Something like this:

> I've faced something similar in my open-source project I'm working on ...

Notice that you don't link to the project or your profile but people who are interested will check your profile. Stated in this way it might just be on the edge of what is allowed in self-promotion.

A similar way could be used if you post a question on Code Review. You select a small piece of your code base with an issue in it that you want to be optimized. In your question you can mention that the code presented is part of a bigger open source project you're running.

Above options are basically how I would interpret the guidance in the earlier linked help center topic:

> **Don't tell - show!** The best way to avoid being seen as a snake-oil salesman is to demonstrate a solution rather than simply asserting the problem can be solved.

I admit that both options are constructed to bend the rules in your favor so don't be disappointed if your posts get downvoted for that. You might want to post on [Quora](http://quora.com) instead for less strict rules.

Answer (score 4):

> "what do you think about this tool"

This is an opinion-based question, and they should not be on SO.

- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
- [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> So if you don't have a blog or want to reach a broader audience

There are a lot different types of social media out there. You could create a Twitter account just for programming-related subjects. I do believe other, more programming-oriented discussions/chats exist out there.

If you don't have a [GitHub](https://github.com/) account, then create one. It's a great way to get people to use your open source project.

Comment: _"I would recommend trying to ask that question on codereview"_ - I disagree. -1. Code review is for code reviews, to get suggestions on how to improve your code. Not to advertise something you've written.

Comment: @Cerbrus if the question is about reviewing the project code then I don't see a problem. It'll get people to check the project out and test it. I did not mean about advertising.

Comment: The OP isn't giving me the impression he wants his code reviewed. It looks like he wants people to look at his tool _*cough*_.

Comment: @Cerbrus now that you mention it. It is true.

Comment: Much better now :-)

Comment: @Cerbrus I actually want both, I don't understand why my question seems so controversial and disliked, I'm just asking if there is a place I can give a github project some visibility so people could try it and eventually if they have time also review the code, so I can know if it's useful in any way and properly written or not , how asking that is bad ? Please explain

Comment: Just because people dislike your post does not mean they don't like what you wrote, but just that they are saying "Yeah those type of questions aren't for SO." - You have a lot of options - twitter - facebook - plow - website demonstrating examples. You can still get people to review your code, if you ask specific questions regarding areas of your code that could be improved.

Comment: @FrançoisRichard of course you can be trusted as a legit user but there are lot of cases where users start spamming their (commercial) stuff. That isn't something that fits in the Q/A model within the SE network.

Comment: @FrançoisRichard: The only option you have on the SE network, is codereview, ___only___ to have your code reviewed. You _can't_ use the SE network to give the project some visibility and to get people to use it.

Comment: @rene that's why I'm asking, because I suspected SO is not the right place to advertise your stuff, I'm asking if anyone knows some platforms more adapted for this, and right if you have followers on your programming twitter it could work but what if you have any of those social media option ? isn't any other options ? thanks

Comment: @Cerbrus so what would be other options outside SE ? If you have any idea to share

Comment: Plenty of alternatives have been mentioned already. Besides, that discussion isn't really on-topic for SO meta.

Comment: @Cerbrus , only options not answering what I asked  but thanks anyway.

Comment: @FrançoisRichard as Cerbrus mentioned, advertising tools/software is off-topic of SO meta. _Only options not answering what I asked_... People might not KNOW how to answer it here. You're asking in the wrong place. I've never had to advertise my projects, I couldn't give you a better answer than what's been provided already if I wanted to. I'm sure many people here are in the same situation.

Comment: I'm asking is it a specific platform you know to promote new libraries for example and the answer is use twitter. Then just say you don't know, not "use twitter" or "get out of here how dare you asking such a question here". Because it's so outrageous ... seriously ?

Answer (score 2):

If your GitHub project is a library or component which can be used by other developers, then, I guess it's ok to advertise it in the answers when your project may be used to solve the asker problem. For example, if you see the question like

> How to add the UI control to my web application which allows user to do blah-blah

Then you can answer like

> You can get my free component from this (link) GitHub page which does exactly what you want. Here's the instruction on how to integrate and setup it to solve your problem (instruction follows).

You must explicitly state that you are the author of this component. Also you should not post such questions by yourself (where using your product would be an answer) or ask your friends to post them and eagerly answer. Play fair and if your library/component is actually good, you will get enough attention to your project from the StackOverflow community.

Further reading: [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).